# I can't post comments

Tags: bug

Increasingly, I'm finding that when I click on 'Post a comment', the comment box refuses to open. Is it something about my computer?

Comment: If you have any, try disabling your extensions (incognito mode would probably work too). If that doesn’t fix the problem, then you need to include your system info in your question (what OS and browser).

Comment: Perhaps you should try the "add a comment" link instead?

Comment: Just kidding. When that happens I try a force refresh of the page (hold the shift key and click the refresh button) and it usually clears whatever problem there was.

Comment: @Robusto I meant 'Add', of course. Luckily the problem hasn't recurred for a few days. Just refreshing didn't work, but next time it happens I'll try holding the shift key as well. Thanks.

Comment: I came here to post a link to a similar problem, albeit it seems more grave https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349484/223820

Comment: @Robusto - Note that for Windows users a hard (forced) refresh is done with the ctrl key rather than the shift key. Hold ctrl and click the refresh button, or ctrl-f5.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Either works for me on Windows.